# Leading zeros not retained while reading ms excel with apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I am trying to read .xlsx file in java (using Apache POI API)  whose cell contain values having leading zeros. e.g 0590040100000124

But in output i get something like this

6247241.0 <->   5.90040100000124E14 <->     0.0 <->     5.90020100000125E14 <-> 
 Here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("C://dedup//dedup.xlsx"));
    String sheetName= workbook.getSheetName(0);
    System.out.println("Sheet Name:"+sheetName);
    double cellValues[] = new double[1000];

     for (int i = 0; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);


            int cellIndex=0;

            for (Row row : sheet) {
                for (Cell cell : row) {
                        //if(cell.toString()!=null){
                         cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
                        cellValues[cellIndex]=cell.getNumericCellValue();
                        cellIndex++;
                        //}
                    }
            }
            for(int k=0;k<cellValues.length;k++)
                System.out.print(cellValues[k]+" <-> "+"\t");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("JKB Exception Message:"+e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: read the cell content as a String then use this string to create your value

Comment: @jhamon even if u read the value as String you get the same output

Comment: What happens if you concatenate a single quote to the beginning of the values?

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that you're fetching the value as a double (Numbers in Excel are,except for a few edge cases, stored as floating point numbers). Floating point numbers printed from Java have no leading zeros, use scientific format etc

Assuming what you really wanted was "give me a string that looks like what Excel shows for this cell", then you don't want to be printing the raw double value. Instead, you need to use the [DataFormatter class](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html), which provides methods which read the Excel format rules applied to a cell, then re-creates (as best it can) those in Java

Your code should be:

```
DataFormatter fmt = new DataFormatter();

String numberAsInExcel = fmt.formatCellValue(cell);
```

That will format the number based on the formatting rules applied in Excel, so should return it looking as you expect, with leading zero, non-scientific format etc